# Worksheet Change to run macro

Tags: vba, excel

My workbook contains several sheets, each with multiple checkboxes.  All checkboxes in all worksheets have the linked cell in row 80.  In a worksheet called "Info" I am using countif to count the total number of times the text "TRUE" occurs in row(s) 80 for all worksheets.  The total is in Info!B8.

I need to call a macro each time cell Info!b8 changes.  So in other words; every time a checkbox is clicked, the linked cell changes, cell Info!b8 goes up or down and I need a macro to run.

This is the code I am using, but it doesn't do anything.  I have researched this and from what I can tell it should work??

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$8" Then
        Call CreateFinalWorksheet
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Form Controls or ActiveX Controls? Also `Sub CreateFinalWorksheet()` is in a normal module without `Private` at the front?

Comment: From Controls and Sub CreateFinalWorksheet() is a normal module with out Private.

Comment: using this to add the checkboxes, but I am already counting the linked cells and using cell b8 in worksheet "Info" to record all clicks.  I just need to run the macro is that cell changes.

Comment: For Each c In rngCB
  With c
    Set myCBX = ws.CheckBoxes.Add _
      (Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, _
       Height:=.Height, Left:=.Left)
  End With
  With myCBX
    .Name = "cbx_" & c.Address(0, 0)
    .LinkedCell = c.Offset(78, 0) _
        .Address(external:=True)
    .Caption = strCap
  End With
Next c

Comment: Tried using LinkedCell and Worksheet_Change event, it is not firing. Worksheet_Change event only fires when user clears/changes values. However you can use the Worksheet_Calculate event. But you have to make a copy of that code to each worksheet - even just a call line, not good for long term maintenance or troubleshoot by others. also requires Auto Calculation mode.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your CheckBoxes are of Form Controls, with a bit of altering the CheckBox Creation, you can achieve what you want without the need of *LinkedCell* and *CountIfs* etc.

Example: **CreateCheckBoxes()** below will create a check box for each cell in Range("D1:D5"), Name it with a prefix and the cell address, assigns the Sub **CheckBoxClicked** when clicked.

In `Sub CheckBoxClicked()`, it will go through all worksheets (except named "Info"), then increment a counter if the value of checkbox named ending **D3** is 1 (ticked). After that, if threshold is met, it calls the `Sub CreateFinalWorksheet()`.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const ChkBoxPrefix As String = "cbx_"
Private Const ThresholdToCreateFinalWorksheet As Long = 3

Sub CreateChkBoxes()
    Dim myCBX As CheckBox, c As Range
    For Each c In Range("D1:D5") 'rngCB
        With c
            Set myCBX = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, Height:=.Height, Left:=.Left)
        End With
        With myCBX
            .Name = ChkBoxPrefix & c.Address(0, 0)
            .Caption = "Check Box " & c.Address(0, 0) 'strCap
            .OnAction = "CheckBoxClicked" ' "CheckBox_Click"
        End With
    Next c
End Sub

Sub CheckBoxClicked() ' CheckBox_Click()
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, lChecked As Long

    On Error Resume Next ' Just in case the named CheckBox does not exist
    lChecked = 0
    For Each oWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If oWS.Name <> "Info" Then
            ' If you need to keep track of more than 1 checkbox in each worksheet, go through them
            ' If you need all of them to be checked before CreateFinalWorksheet, exit when a checkbox.value = 0
            With oWS.CheckBoxes(ChkBoxPrefix & "D3") ' <-- Change to what you need to keep track of
                lChecked = lChecked + IIf(.Value = 1, 1, 0)
            End With
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    If lChecked >= ThresholdToCreateFinalWorksheet Then CreateFinalWorksheet
End Sub

Private Sub CreateFinalWorksheet()
    Debug.Print "CreateFinalWorksheet()"
End Sub
```

Alternatively you put the event `Sub Worksheet_Calculate()` into *Info* module, and check if the **Info!B8** is large enough to call CreateFinalWorksheet.

Comment: I'd collapse `CheckBox_Click()` to the statement `Calculate` only: this will keep the OP's current code and cells as it is and _react_ to any `checkbox` change

Comment: So I finally figured it out and the answer is too simple.  All I had to do was add call createfinalworksheet into Sub Worksheet_Calculate()  No other code was needed.